# Any examples of a custom toolbar where the default toolbar is the same, but the buttons on the right side aren't there(month, agenda,day,week)?

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I am using the react-big-calendar and was wondering if anyone can show an example of a custom toolbar where it was just removing one of the aspects of the given toolbar.

I've tried to hide the given toolbar but I need a part of it, not the whole thing to be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Custom Toolbar example in the Big Calendar documentation. You don't need to hide the button group. Just leave it out entirely.

```js
export default function CustomToolbar({
  // date, // available, but not used here
  label,
  localizer: { messages },
  onNavigate,
  // onView, // available, but not used here
  // view, // available, but not used here
  // views, // available, but not used here
}) {
  return (
    <div className="rbc-toolbar">
      <span className="rbc-toolbar-label">{label}</span>

      <span className={clsx('rbc-btn-group', 'examples--custom-toolbar')}>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => onNavigate(navigate.PREVIOUS)}
          aria-label={messages.previous}
        >
          &#60;
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => onNavigate(navigate.TODAY)}
          aria-label={messages.today}
        >
          &#8226;
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => onNavigate(navigate.NEXT)}
          aria-label={messages.next}
        >
          &#62;
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}
```